# Multiprocessing subprocesses randomly receive SIGTERMs

Tags: python, multiprocessing, signals, sigterm

I'm fiddling with `multiprocessing` and `signal`.
I'm creating a pool, and have the workers catch `SIGTERM`s.
With no apparent reasons, I observe that the subprocesses randomly receive `SIGTERM`s.
Here is a MWE:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import signal
import os
import time

def start_process():
    print("Starting process #{}".format(os.getpid()))

def sigterm_handler(signo, _frame):
    print("Process #{} received a SIGTERM".format(os.getpid()))

def worker(i):
    time.sleep(1)

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, sigterm_handler)
while True:
    with mp.Pool(initializer=start_process) as pool:
        pool.map(worker, range(10))
    time.sleep(2)
```

Output:

```
Starting process #7735
Starting process #7736
Starting process #7737
Starting process #7738
Starting process #7739
Starting process #7740
Starting process #7741
Starting process #7742
Job done.
Starting process #7746
Starting process #7747
Starting process #7748
Starting process #7749
Starting process #7750
Starting process #7751
Starting process #7752
Starting process #7753
Process #7748 received a SIGTERM
Process #7746 received a SIGTERM
Job done.
Starting process #7757
Starting process #7758
Starting process #7759
Starting process #7760
Starting process #7761
Starting process #7762
Starting process #7763
Starting process #7764
```

As you can see, that looks unpredictable.

So, where do these `SIGTERM`s come from?
Is this normal?
Am I guaranteed that the workers will finish their job?
And in the end, is it OK to have the subprocesses capture `SIGTERM`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's normal and can happen while your pool is executing `__exit__` upon leaving the context-manager.
Since the workers have finished their jobs at that point, there's nothing to worry about.
The pool itself causes the `SIGTERM` for workers which don't have an exitcode available when the
pool checks for it. This gets triggered in the `Pool._terminate_pool`-method (Python 3.7.1):

```
    # Terminate workers which haven't already finished.
    if pool and hasattr(pool[0], 'terminate'):
        util.debug('terminating workers')
        for p in pool:
            if p.exitcode is None:
                p.terminate()
```

The pool-workers will get joined a few lines later:

```
    if pool and hasattr(pool[0], 'terminate'):
        util.debug('joining pool workers')
        for p in pool:
            if p.is_alive():
                # worker has not yet exited
                util.debug('cleaning up worker %d' % p.pid)
                p.join()
```

In a scenario where you would call `pool.terminate()` explicitly while your workers
are still running (for example you are using `pool.map_async` and then use `pool.terminate()`),
your application would deadlock waiting on the `p.join()` (unless you let your `sigterm_handler` eventually call `sys.exit())`.

Better don't mess with signal handlers if you don't have to.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. I'm not done yet, but it was definitely the answer I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I think it normal, but can't say anything about the random message printing.  You can get more info, insert this in the main:

```
mp.log_to_stderr(logging.DEBUG)
```

and change the start_process():

```
def start_process():
    proc= mp.current_process()
    print("Starting process #{}, its name is {}".format(os.getpid(),proc.name))
```